# Writing a generic component that accepts 3 parameters in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I am very, very new to react and redux to the point I am slowly trying to work my head around it. In order to get better, I am trying to do a small project where say I make a dropdown component, I can use it elsewhere and would be generic in the sense that it can be used anywhere in the site.  I have done this a non-generic way, but think overtime a component that is generic would be good. The generic one I am having trouble on has 3 parameters that are passed into the list, which they are returned as strings. I understand how to do this, but having trouble on how to get the data to show correctly and displayed.

I have copied the code below here.

```
export const Dropdown = ({
  link,
  iconName,
  itemName,
}: {
  link: string
  iconName: string
  itemName: string
}) => {
   return (
    <a href={link}>
     <FontAwesomeIcon fixedWidth icon={iconName} />
    <span className="Drop_Down_List_Item">{itemName}</span>
    </a>
  ) }
```

Here is what I am thinking I want the details of the dropdowns to be.

```
const Drop_Down_Details = { 
             Header: { 
                link: '' ,
                iconName:'{faTHLarge}' ,
                itemName: 'ProgrammingLanguages' ,
             }
          }
```

Thanks very much for explaining how this works and examples on what to do next, I appreciate it.

Comment: Your question is very broad, and unclear of where you are stuck? we are not going to write a complete react component for you where exactly are you stuck and can't figure out how to get it working?

Comment: somebody build something exactly like this. maybe look at his work and get ideas from there: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as i'm going to help you:

You need to add a list of options or menus in your dropdown, with the class you gave, you can add it as an array as props. Say:

```
export const Dropdown = ({
  links : Drop_Down_Details[]
})
```

then you can show them in your dropdown with a map function in your render method as follows:

```
<div>
  {this.props.links.map(link => ( 
    <a href={link.link}>{link.ItemName}</a>
  ));}
</div>
```

you can look at this example: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown
here is his code: https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown/blob/master/index.js